# I need an explanation on why I need to vertical align twice to make my image center

Tags: html, css

So I'm trying to make a holder which has a fixed height and width. Inside this holder I want to place images who adjust their height and width based on this holder. It all works, but I have difficulties understanding how the vertical align works. **Why do I have to give an alignment to both the div with the helper class and to the product-image class?** I don't understand why I need to use this div with the helper class to make it work.

```css
.product-holder {
  position: absolute;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  margin: 15px 15px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}

.helper {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.product-image {
  max-height: 240px;
  max-width: 240px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="product-holder">
  <div class="helper"> </div>
  <img class="product-image" src="http://cdn3-www.dogtime.com/assets/uploads/2011/01/file_23262_entlebucher-mountain-dog-300x189.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: This is when you [should use flexbox](https://codepen.io/ksiabani/pen/ZXYEwg).

Comment: Thanks bro, very helpful indeed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `text-align` to horizontally align elements, `left`, `right` and `center` mean align with the left edge, right edge and center of their **containing block** respectively.

Vertical alignment is very different.

Inline-level elements vertically align with **each other**, and not with their containing block.

The helper is the height of the containing block, so its vertical middle is halfway up the containing block.

Your vertical alignments are saying: place a horizontal line through the **vertical middle** of the helper div and a horizontal line through the **vertical middle** of the image such that the two horizontal lines join up to make a single horizontal line.

If you only set the helper to `vertical-align:middle`, then you're saying: place a horizontal line through the **vertical middle** of the helper div and a horizontal line through the **bottom** of the image such that the two horizontal lines join up to make a single horizontal line.

If you only set the image to `vertical-align:middle`, then you're saying: place a horizontal line through the **bottom** of the helper div and a horizontal line through the **vertical middle** of the image such that the two horizontal lines join up to make a single horizontal line.

If you set neither to `vertical-align:middle`, then you're saying: place a horizontal line through the **bottom** of the helper div and a horizontal line through the **bottom** of the image such that the two horizontal lines join up to make a single horizontal line.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful dude

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to solve the centering as done below: A relative/absolute relationship between `DIV` and `img` and `top: 50%`, `left: 50%` and `transform: translate(-50%, -50%)`. No additional element needed. And with better browser compatibility than a flexbox solution.

```css
.product-holder {
  position: relative;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  margin: 15px 15px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.product-image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  max-height: 240px;
  max-width: 240px;
}
```

```html
<div class="product-holder">
  <img class="product-image" src="http://cdn3-www.dogtime.com/assets/uploads/2011/01/file_23262_entlebucher-mountain-dog-300x189.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: Unless you need to support ancient browsers, flexbox has [great compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: Well, some people use ancient browsers, that's why I added this remark...

Answer (score 0):

So, unless you need to support very old browsers, and since others offered alternatives to your problem, I post mine too, based on **flexbox**:

```
.product-holder {
  position: absolute;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  margin: 15px 15px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.product-image {
  max-height: 240px;
  max-width: 240px;
}
```

[**Codepen demo**](https://codepen.io/ksiabani/pen/ZXYEwg)

[**More on flexbox**](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

[**Browser compatibility**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes#Browser_compatibility)